# Windows Server 2008 R2 нет интернета на пк в домене когда сервер выключен

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

решил попробовать поднять домен в локальной сети, установил виртуалку Windows server 2008 R2 настроил AD и DNS, DHCP не ставил все пк на статике, роутер раздает интернет как шлюз, в итоге все работает интернет есть ввожу пк в домен все тоже нормально, но если сервер выключился то на этих пк пропадает интернет. Что я делаю не так ? Помогите решить проблему если так можно сделать чтоыб интернет был даже если сервер выключился.
Вот такие настройки стоят
Роутер
ip - 192.168.0.254
Сервер
ip - 192.168.0.200/24
dns1 - 127.0.0.1
dns2 - 192.168.0.200
ПК в домене
ip - 192.168.0.9/24
gateway - 192.168.0.254
dns - 192.168.0.200

Comment: Ну если вы настроили dns на сервер, то вполне логично, что он перестаёт работать, когда сервер выключается